# unzip in google colab corrupts after first read

Tags: unzip, large-files

I have uploaded a 11GB images file into my google drive, and trying to unzip in colab for processing. First time it processes properly. After colab session is closed and restarted the next day, the same unzip command fails saying the zip file is corrupted. So I had to remove corrupted zip file, load original zip file again and use it colab. Again first time works perfectly fine, but second time it fails again. Every time uploading 11GB file to google drive takes lot of time, and uses so much bandwidth.

I am using !unzip '/content/drive/My Drive/CheXpert-v1.0-small.zip to unzip. 
Second time also it starts unzipping, but after few records, it throws an error saying read error on a specific image, which is different every time. If I restart unzip again, it gives offset errors without unzipping any image.

Is there any way to fix this problem, so that I can unzip successfully any number of times?

Thanks in advance for a quick help.

Comment: I would suggest uploading the unzip version of files and storing it in a folder in your drive. After that mount your drive in your notebook and directly access all the files through their path. uploading might take a lot of time but I think this is the better alternative than unzipping 11 Gb of data.

Comment: Thanks, Jigar. That would take training process a very long time! However, issue seems to be exceeding daily download quota for my google drive! Since the file size is 11GB, i may be running out of quota each time I access it from colab! Unfortunately, we don't know what is the size of daily quota is!

Comment: Post the answer if you can resolve it. All the best and sorry that I couldn't help you.

Comment: Yes, it indeed is due to reaching daily quota on google drive. Same file when I try the next day, it works. The issue is when you are accessing from colab, google drive does no t communicate to colab that I had exceeded my daily quota, but does not let colab access it. Colab since it is unable to access it, throughs zip file open error and indicates that zip file may have been corrupted!

Comment: Same issue here I still am unable to find a work around